# Rails auto convert query string params to integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement a form of pagination using limit and offset query parameters. Is there a way to make sure the values are integers otherwise throw a 400 error, perhaps by using strong_parameters? It seems like the sort of thing that would be built in to rails, but I can't find anything.

I could just manually convert the query parameters, but I'd rather use something a bit more bullet proof if possible.

Comment: why not use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) or [kamanari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for pagination?

Comment: I'd prefer to use limit/offset over page numbers, and this is primarily a JSON api, which doesn't seem to be supported as well in either gem

Comment: the gems internally convert per_page/page_number to limit/offset anyway. Hence the suggestion. JSon API? you omitted that tiny little detail from the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like the commenter @Litmus above, I would recommend using a Ruby gem such as [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) to manage pagination.

But if you're set on rolling your own, and you're concerned about input sanitization, the simplest method to ensure the "offset" and "limit" parameters are integers might be a filter in your controller:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :sanitize_page_params

  # ... other controller methods ...

  private

  def sanitize_page_params
    params[:offset] = params[:offset].to_i
    params[:limit] = params[:limit].to_i
  end

  # ... etc. ...

end
```

Note that strings such as `"foo"` will be converted to `0`.

Comment: FYI. The code above will convert the params[:offset] value set to "-1" to -1. If this negative integer is then used in the ActiveRecord.offset() call, it will result in  a 'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error' error

Comment: Steve Wilhelm makes a great point ^ If you use this, you may also want to check for negative numbers.

Comment: Little update since `before_filter` syntax were deprecated in Rails 5.0 and removed in Rails 5.1 :
Use `before_action` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to convert your parameters manually. Ideally, abstract this into a controller-method to keep your actual method clean.

```
Class SomeController < ActionController
  before_filter: cleanup_pagination_params

  def cleanup_pagination_params
    params[:offset] = params[:offset].to_i
    params[:limit]  = params[:limit].to_i
  end

  # Your regular controller methods here
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Repair numeric param values converted into string

```
repair_nested_params({id: '11', age: '25'}) # Sample

def repair_nested_params(obj)
  obj.each do |key, value|
    obj[key] = parse_string(value)
  end
end

def parse_string(value)
  return repair_nested_params(value) if value.is_a?(Hash)
  return value.map(&method(:repair_nested_params)) if value.is_a?(Array)
  return value unless value.is_a?(String)

  is_numeric = value.match?(/\A[-+]?\d*\.?\d+\z/)
  return value unless is_numeric

  (value.to_f % 1).positive? ? value.to_f : value.to_i
end
```